# Visible Signature in a PDF file

Tags: pdf, pades

I 'm trying to create a visible signature in a PDF file.

Taking a simple PDF "hello world" file:

```
%PDF-1.7

1 0 obj  % entry point
<<
  /Type /Catalog
  /Pages 2 0 R
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Pages
  /MediaBox [ 0 0 200 200 ]
  /Count 1
  /Kids [ 3 0 R ]
>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Page
  /Parent 2 0 R
  /Resources <<
    /Font <<
      /F1 4 0 R 
    >>
  >>
  /Contents 5 0 R
>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Font
  /Subtype /Type1
  /BaseFont /Times-Roman
>>
endobj

5 0 obj  % page content
<<
  /Length 44
>>
stream
BT
10 05 TD
/F1 12 Tf
(Hello, world!) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj

xref
0 6
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000010 00000 n 
0000000079 00000 n 
0000000173 00000 n 
0000000301 00000 n 
0000000380 00000 n 
trailer
<<
  /Size 6
  /Root 1 0 R
>>
startxref
492
%%EOF
```

And signing it with a text to appear "Yolo" at some position at the first page produces this:

```
%PDF-1.7

1 0 obj  % entry point
<<
  /Type /Catalog
  /Pages 2 0 R
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Pages
  /MediaBox [ 0 0 200 200 ]
  /Count 1
  /Kids [ 3 0 R ]
>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Page
  /Parent 2 0 R
  /Resources <<
    /Font <<
      /F1 4 0 R 
    >>
  >>
  /Contents 5 0 R
>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Font
  /Subtype /Type1
  /BaseFont /Times-Roman
>>
endobj

5 0 obj  % page content
<<
  /Length 44
>>
stream
BT
10 05 TD
/F1 12 Tf
(Hello, world!) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj

xref
0 6
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000010 00000 n 
0000000079 00000 n 
0000000173 00000 n 
0000000301 00000 n 
0000000380 00000 n 
trailer
<<
  /Size 6
  /Root 1 0 R
>>
startxref
492
%%EOF
8 0 obj
<</F 132/Type/Annot/Subtype/Widget/Rect[0 0 0 0]/FT/Sig/DR<<>>/T(Signature1)/V 6 0 R/P 3 0 R/AP<</N 7 0 R>>>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Contents <...>/Type/Sig/SubFilter/ETSI.CAdES.detached/M(D:20190626125540+00'00')/ByteRange [0 824 60826 1401]/Filter/Adobe.PPKLite>>
endobj
9 0 obj
<</BaseFont/Helvetica/Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Name/Helv>>
endobj
10 0 obj
<</BaseFont/ZapfDingbats/Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/Name/ZaDb>>
endobj
12 0 obj
<</Length 35>>stream
BT
1 15 TD
/Helv 6 Tf
(Yolo) Tj
ET

endstream
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Type/XObject/Resources<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]>>/Subtype/Form/BBox[0 0 0 0]/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0]/Length 8/FormType 1/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
xœ    
endstream
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 4 0 R>>>>/Contents [12 0 R 5 0 R]/Annots[8 0 R]>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/MediaBox[0 0 200 200]/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<</AcroForm<</Fields[8 0 R]/DR<</Font<</Helv 9 0 R/ZaDb 10 0 R>>>>/DA(/Helv 0 Tf 0 g )/SigFlags 3>>/Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj
11 0 obj
<</Producer(AdES Tools https://www.turboirc.com)/ModDate(D:20190626125540+00'00')>>
endobj
xref
0 4
0000000000 65535 f 
0000061604 00000 n 
0000061529 00000 n 
0000061414 00000 n 
6 7
0000000804 00000 n 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000679 00000 n 
0000060952 00000 n 
0000061050 00000 n 
0000061746 00000 n 
0000061127 00000 n 
trailer
<</Root 1 0 R/Prev 492/Info 11 0 R/Size 17/ID[<4BB225C2F629BB21464F66FBF2FED264><8E3C9AD8354C66931EAAC282088455EA>]>>
startxref
61846
%%EOF
```

So there is an object in the PDF that shows some text in the first page:

```
12 0 obj
<</Length 35>>stream
BT
1 15 TD
/Helv 6 Tf
(Yolo) Tj
ET

endstream
endobj
```

My problem is now that this object is treated like a common text object in adobe reader. I want it, when clicked, to go to the digital signature, like how Adobe Acrobat signs the documents.

What do I miss? Is there a parameter in the digital signature (The 6 or 8 number object) or in any of the other objects my app puts in the new PDF that links the text object with the signature?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object 8

```
8 0 obj
<</F 132/Type/Annot/Subtype/Widget/Rect[0 0 0 0]/FT/Sig/DR<<>>/T(Signature1)/V 6 0 R/P 3 0 R/AP<</N 7 0 R>>>>
endobj
```

is an AcroForm form field for signatures (as the **FT** entry with value **Sig** tells us). At the same time, though, this object also is a form field widget annotation (as can be seen in the **Type** and **Subtype** entries). Form field widget annotations are the visual representations of form fields, and if a form field has only one representation, the widget can be merged with the form field as in your object.

In your case the annotation has a 0x0 size (`/Rect[0 0 0 0]`), i.e. invisible. To have a visible representation, you need an annotation rectangle that does not vanish.

The content that is displayed is defined in the normal appearance `/AP<</N 7 0 R>>` which points to object 7.

```
7 0 obj
<</Type/XObject/Resources<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]>>/Subtype/Form/BBox[0 0 0 0]/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0]/Length 8/FormType 1/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
xœ    
endstream
endobj
```

At first glance this looks pretty empty, even after decompression.

Thus, what you have to do is

- choose a non-vanishing rectangle for your signature form field annotation,
- adapt the **BBox** of the normal appearance stream to that annotation rectangle, and
- create a non-empty content in the normal appearance stream of that annotation instead of adding page content.

Furthermore you should fix obvious errors in your PDF, e.g.

- object 7, your signature field normal appearance, is marked as free in your cross references
- your trailer claims a size of 17

---

For details please study the PDF specification ISO 32000. Part 1 is published for download by Adobe at https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

In particular sections

- 12.5 "Annotations"
- 12.7 "Interactive Forms"
- 12.8 "Digital Signatures"

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I 'll try it and notify you soon.

Comment: It works. One more question if you don't mind. The /Rect is rect coordinates, where the text wants a BT and a Td (`BT 10 05 TD ... `). Is there a way to use a Rect for the text as well?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Nonetheless, I just saw that there is another thing to do, the **BBox** in the appearance stream must not vanish either.

Comment: @mki the text appears in left-bottom coordinates (10,5) , while the signature rect is a rect. Is there a way to have the text appear in a rect, rather than a xy only?

Comment: Well, you can choose the coordinates top be inside the rectangle. More exactly, you should choose them so. Thus, simply choose the coordinates accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps you can help on that as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75267976/visible-signature-in-pdf-file-2